# Mouseenter Mouseleave issue

Tags: javascript, mouseover, mouseleave, mouseenter

I have the following html

```
<div class="a-class">
   <img src="image" alt="" />
   <div class="b-class"></div>
</div>
```

I am using

```
jQuery('.a-class').mouseleave(function() {
     //blah blah
});
```

The problem is that `b-class` is "overlayed" ontop of `a-class` for part of it - so everytime I move the mouse over the overlay of `b-class` - it fires `mouseleave`

Is there any way I can ignore `b-class` for this ? Thought maybe:

```
jQuery('.a-class').not('.b-class').mouseleave(function() {
         //blah blah
    });
```

But that doesn't work ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to mouseover image and not the div below it.. 
You should target the image only and not exclude something.

```
jQuery('.a-class img').mouseleave(function() {
     //blah blah
});
```

Edit:

Right.. So, ive done something like this before.. Its actually ongoing project.

`Mouseleave` is the thing that actually solves this. I had similar problem with my project because i was using `mouseout` which kept dropping the ball.

http://jsfiddle.net/SaPcE/ here you should notice that `mouseleave` doesnt drop the `mouseenter` function But if you change `mouseleave` to `mouseout`, that will happen.

So.. you shouldnt have a problem is what im saying i guess.

---

Because i think you might be doing something much similar as mine and my friends project, you might want to check this out http://photoshopmesta.net/sic/theTest/

And this is the main site http://photoshopmesta.net/sic/

Sic is free to use even commercially so that shouldnt be a big show stopper. Theres currently in version ( 1.2 )  a little chrome issue with fancybox ( image viewer ) that it uses but it will be fixed.. ( We dont support ie6, so if you want that.. SIC is not the way to go. It might work in ie6.. somewhat? but we dont really know or care. )

Comment: thanks for the response. The problem however still exists - because even if I target the img - the `b-class` is overlayed ontop of the image. So as soon as move over `b-class` - it's fires the mouse leave ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Which will hopefully satisfy your needs.